# Does Google not count certain words in search queries

Tags: google-search

Does Google not count certain words in search queries? If so which words?

I remember hearing somewhere that woulds such as "how to" and "in" get discounted so if you searched for a "painter in new york" Google would query their index with "painter new york".

Is this correct?

Comment: painter in new york is pretty general, is that a house painter or portrait painter you're looking for? Google will use all words in some exceptions as listed below and who knows how else based on your location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Google does not use all the words in your query to display search results - at least not all the time.

There does not seem to be a list for all the words that are in a query but which Google might not consider when displaying search results; likely they are articles (a, an, the), prepositions (of, on, in) and - possibly, and depending on the context - frequent verbs like be, is, are, go, was, went.

Google lists its policy on [this site](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134479) under Exceptions, though:

[image: Google Exceptions]

Comment: Not correct, Google does use all terms in the query, because if you search for the who you'll see Google uses both The and Who in the search query. `search?hl=en&safe=off&q=the+who`

Comment: @Anagio this is clearly called out as an exception to the rule in the first point...

Comment: @MikeHudson saying Google does not count certain words isn't true. They clearly do weather it's an exception to a query or not. It's only a few examples Google gives us. Searching `painter new york` and `painter in new york` does not generate the same exact search results they are quite different.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect that Google may or may not take some words into consideration when displaying search results. I have made a distinction between query (what you enter in Google) and search results (what Google displays). Everyone who uses Google on a daily basis must have noted that Google does not use ALL the words when displaying search results.